# Как сделать input range с двумя тумблерами?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть два `input range` (посмотреть можно [тут](https://codepen.io/EYur/pen/WdRJGK))

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#range').on('change', function(){
    $('#tmbVal').text($(this).val());
  });
    $('#range2').on('change', function(){
    $('#tmbVal2').text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
/* Полоса range */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #9bbedc;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
/* Тумблер */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #7ca5c7;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -6.6px;
}
/* Фокус на полосу range */
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #7ca5c7;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #65001c;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 39px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #ac51b5;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ac51b5;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #65001c;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #ac51b5;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ac51b5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
      <div id="tmbVal">0</div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="range2" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
        <div id="tmbVal2">0</div> 
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как из двух сделать один input range с двумя тумблерами? Заранее всем большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Средствами html - никак. Необходимо использовать javascript. Если требуется простое решение, можете воспользоваться `https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Comment: А я про html и не говорил) Требуется объединить два моих input'a в один, но с двумя ползунками)

Comment: в метках js не указан ;-). А мой вариант Вам не подходит, ссылка вверху

Comment: прошу прощения, метку добавил) Я его пробовал, но возник вопрос:1) вот этот файл я не нашел <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> где его можно скачать?

Comment: конечно, он же реализован с помощью `div, span` элементов. Там необходимо скачать файл с темой ( на сайте есть), либо можете сами написать стили, либо стащить стиль со страницы демо

Comment: Тему тоже скачивал, но нужного файла там не нашел. Там написано, что якобы 
 
<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
 
<div id="slider-range"></div>

Это и есть input range..А где собственно input[type=range], на что стили накладывать?))

Comment: после выполнения скрипта, у Вас появляются новые элементы, посмотрите в инспекторе браузера (ф12)

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ)

Comment: если будут проблемы, обращайтесь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо использовать javascript. Если требуется простое решение, можете воспользоваться например [|jQuery UI Slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)